# Як перекласти "hustler" (роль у команді на хакатоні)?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Як можна перекласти українською hustler в контексті хакатону? І чи потрібно перекладати взагалі? Чи не доцільніше просто транслітерувати як "х/гаслер"?

Англійські визначення слова:

> one who is active and energetic in business<sup>[[The Century Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_Dictionary): [на wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/hustler), [на finedictionary](http://www.finedictionary.com/hustler.html)]</sup>; an aggressively ambitious person<sup>[[Wordsmyth](https://www.wordsmyth.net/?rid=20109)]</sup>; an enterprising person determined to succeed<sup>[[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hustler?s=t)]</sup>; go-getter<sup>[[dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hustler?s=t)]</sup>.

Переклад<sup>[користувачем [bytebuster](/u/8)]</sup>:

> той, хто активний та енергійний у бізнесі; агресивно амбітна особа; завзята (ініціативна) особа, що зосереджена на досягнення успіху; ділок.

Ну і найважливіше - це має бути роль учасника команди на хакатоні (поряд із хакером і хіпстером).

Comment: Варто було б додати опис цього поняття. А так - *бізнес-мозок*.

Comment: Додав базовий переклад з англійської

Comment: А чим це відрізняється від решти учасників команди хакатону? Хіба не всі учасники повинні бути зосередженими на досягненні успіху, чи бути завзятими та активними? Чи, може, ми маємо потребу в тому, щоби підкреслити цю людину як найактивнішу в команді? Як якогось лідера тощо?

Answer (score 3):

Дійсно, у стартап-культурі виділяють три ключові ролі: `hacker`, `hipster`, `hustler`:

1. Хакер відповідає за технологічну частину.
2. Хіпстер переймається тим, щоб продукт мав гарний вигляд.
3. Хаслер "запаковує" продукт і продає його.

Фактично, hustler - це salesperson, а, отже, найкращим відповідником є **продавець**.

Comment: Радий вашому поверненню! Не забувайте, будь ласка, надавати джерела.

Comment: Дякую. Щодо джерел, то мені важко знайти першоджерело цієї класифікації. Однак, швидкий пошук в Google показує, що така класифікація є розповсюдженою і подвійного трактування немає.